# Please tell me How to replace in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I tried the following, but it did not work. Can someone please tell me how to write it correctly?

re comment = comment.replaceAll('/....$/',"")

Comment: _What_ did not work. Please be specific about the error you get or what problem you are facing.

Comment: I wanted to get rid of "(R2)",so I wrote this.                          comment = 2020(R2)                                                             re comment = comment.replaceAll('....$/',"")                       But "2020(R2)" was the result.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69971823/3181392) the question. Comments are not a good place to share code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't really clear what the requirements are but if you start with a `String` like `'2020(R2)'` you can remove the `(R2)` any number of ways, depending on what assumptions you can make about the input data.  For example:

```
String comment = '2020(R2)'

String result1 = comment.replace('(R2)', '')
String result2 = comment[0..-5]

int index = comment.indexOf('(R2)')

String result3 = comment.substring(0, index)
```